# Facebook Javascript API: matching a login to a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When using the Javascript API login, it returns to the page with a number of parameters, like the access token, the user ID, and other details. If I wanted to associate a user in my database with this Facebook user, which would be the piece of data I want to store to be able to look it up later for authentication?

In other words, which token should I store, so that next time the user logs in, I can look in the database for this token and authenticate the user?

I would use the UID, but it seems easy to spoof another UID and impersonate someone else.

Thanks!

Comment: do you only use the js api or also a server side api like php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side spoofing is not your concern.  If you are displaying FB content based upon FB authentication, then FB is responsible for the integrity of that process.

If you are using this info server side, then you need to follow the OAuth 2.0 flow which is not spoofable (to my knowledge) because you are going directly to FB for authentication.

You can't mix the two flows because you leave yourself vulnerable to attacks.

And to answer your other question, yes, you should link your DB to the UID because the access_token will change.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the fb access token with the fb js sdk. So you can take the fb-uid as save. The tokens you get from fb are only valid for a limited time, so you shouldn't save them.

**UPDATE:**
Regarding the saveness of the fb-uid: Your PHP script gets a signed request from facebook. That request is signed with your app's secret so that no one else can read that data. The request contains a fb-session for the current user (including the uid) and an access token.